# Маппинг проперти у объекта из параметров конструктора

Tags: c#, потоки-данных, automapper

Пытаюсь замаппить поля объекта, который является параметром конструктора внешнего объекта. Что-то не получается это сделать по-нормальному. Вот мои классы:

```
public class Image
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
    public string ImageMimeType { get; set; }
}

public class ImageDownloadResponse
{
    public ImageDownloadResponse(ImageMetaData metaData, Stream stream)
    {
        DownloadedImageMetadata = metaData;
        ImageByteStream = stream;
    }
    public ImageMetaData DownloadedImageMetadata;
    public Stream ImageByteStream;
}

public class ImageMetaData
{
    public ImageMetaData(Guid imageId, string imageMimeType)
    {
        ImageId = imageId;
        ImageMimeType = imageMimeType;
    }
    public Guid ImageId;
    public string ImageMimeType;
}
```

А вот одна из попыток все это дело заммапить (код не валидный):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Image, ImageDownloadResponse>()
    .ConstructUsing(x => new ImageDownloadResponse(new ImageMetaData(x.Id, x.ImageMimeType), Stream.Null ))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.DownloadedImageMetadata,
                opt => new ImageMetaData(opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id), opt.MapFrom(src => src.ImageMimeType)))
    .AfterMap((image, response) =>
    {
        response.ImageByteStream = new MemoryStream(image.ImageData);
    });
```

Но, к сожалению, я не могу инстанцировать объект в области видимости option. Еще мне кажется, что конвентировать массив байт в stream в разделе `AfterMap` не очень круто.

Как это реализовать?

Comment: Так: `.ForCtorParam("metaData", expression => { new ImageMetaData(expression.MapFrom(src => src.Id), expression.MapFrom(src => src.ImageMimeType))})` тоже не сработает:(

Comment: Сделал пока следующим образом: `.ForCtorParam("metaData", opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new ImageMetaData(src.Id, src.ImageMimeType)))`
Проверить пока возможности нет, если уверены, что так не получится, пожалуйста сообщите:)